# Will unusual traffic to my web site from AdFly hurt rankings?

Tags: seo, ranking

The situation is some one is trying to hurt my ranking by submitting link to my web site in AdFly.

Could this could hurt my SEO?  If so,how can I stop it or reduce it? I already try to delete the page that they target, but they change the link to another page of the web site.

Comment: How would Google find out about this?   Google can't see the traffic to your website, it only knows about links that its crawler can find.   Generally ads made not crawlable and will not effect SEO.

Comment: Stephen is right: how can Google find the link to click on? So long as Google can't find the ad and can't follow the link, it isn't a huge deal. Even if Google could find the ad and follow the link, it may not be a problem (could help with exposure for you!). If you get really worried about the link or see severe negatives with it, you can always remove the page linked to (with a 410) or reach out to AdFly and ask for removal or (more extreme) disavow those links.

Comment: Are you talking about referral traffic found in Google Analytics?? If so, it is more of the referrer spam that Google seems to be happy with. Otherwise harmless and should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your answers,  another thing is , i have adsense adds in this web site and due to this trafic that come from the g.gs (adfly link) i notice some income up by 150% , and i am worried that google could ban my account, and as a precaution i remove the adsense adds from the web site

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your inquiry as to if Google will penalize you due to the inbound links from AdFly this won't cause any issues as Google can not see traffic coming into your site. In addition even if Google could see the traffic coming in Google doesn't care if you get  high amount of traffic to your site, only if you are performing blackhat SEO techniques.

As for the second part of it where you talk in the comments about your AdSense there is no issue with traffic coming into your site triggering an increase in your AdSense revenue. At the end of the day what this other entity is doing with paying for advertising for your site is outside of your control and only serves to increase traffic to your site which can be considered a plus.

Comment: thanks you for you answer , the only thing that i notice is that my websites rank hase drope dramatically ,so this is a way of atake a websites seo , i  can relate because the bounce rate hase raise.